# Which toolbox does randsample belong in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) indicates that randsample belongs to statistics and machine learning toolbox. I have an earlier version of Matlab so it does not show in the list of toolboxes. Is there a way to find out which toolbox a function belongs in the current installation of matlab?

Comment: Try `which randsample` from the Matlab command line. If it is not found -- then your version does not support it. But it should be relatively easy to write such a function from scratch. Better be more specific in what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the documentation shipped with your version of MATLAB. If you search for the function name it shows which toolbox it belongs to. (At least my version does this.)

Comment: Or type `doc randsample` to directly open that function's documentation, in which you will see which toolbox the function belongs to.